# NSString comes in as a NSMutableArray in a Titanium module

Tags: iphone, sqlite, titanium, titanium-modules

```
-(id)select:(NSString *)original_query
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char * converted = [original_query UTF8String];

    NSLog(@"[INFO] converted char = %s", converted);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, converted, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName: @"DB Encriptor" reason: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Query \"%s\" has failed, we could not execute the SQL statement. '%s'",  converted, sqlite3_errmsg(db) ] userInfo: nil];
    }
    else {
        @try {
             ...
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

When the execution reaches the line :

```
const char * converted = [original_query UTF8String];
```

I get the following error:

```
 2013-06-27 02:17:33.505 proof[25200:3c03] -[__NSArrayM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc954a30
```

This is probably a very simple and silly error, I've spent hours trying different schemas to convert the string or even a **[NSMutableArray description]** to UTF8 but no success so far.
I am creating a native iOS module to work along Titanium. I call this method from JavaScript (in Titanium) passing a string, something like:

```
 encriptmydb.select("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;")
```

But the error persists ...

Comment: This looks very similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335137/error-converting-nsstring-to-utf8string.

Comment: Perhaps add `NSLog(@"%@", original_query)` to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Yes Martin, it is indeed. But as I found out the problem was different I decided to open another thread and see if any other ideas could come up. NSLog as you suggested prints normally on the screen :(

Comment: Can you show the NSLog output?

Comment: I think I did it earlier but I can't do it anymore. When I try to print it on the screen nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the sample module guide here 
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules

basically what is happening is that the arguments are being passed in as an array, you need to just pull off the first one to get the string parameter

See the parameter passing example here

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/moddevguide/mobile/ios/Classes/TiModdevguideParametersDemoProxy.m

Comment: Thank you, Aaron .. That was the glitch.